# Returning JSON to OutputBuffer

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am having issues when returning a JSON string back to an output after I deserialized it.

I have the following three classes declared that I generated from json2csharp:

```
public class Application
{
    public int App_ID { get; set; }
    public string App_Ref { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Error_Code { get; set; }
    public string Error_Message { get; set; }
    public string Create_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Modify_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Client_Name { get; set; }
    public string Client_Code { get; set; }
    public string Centrelink_Status { get; set; }

}
public class Response
{
    public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public string Current_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Last_App_Dt { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Response jsonResponse { get; set; }

}
```

My JSON Response looks like this:

```
    {
      "Success": true,
      "Response": {
        "Applications": [
          {
            "App_ID": 2877582,
            "App_Ref": "Odonnell",
            "Status": "Complete",
            "Error_Code": 0,
            "Error_Message": "",
            "Create_Dt": "2016-10-09 19:28:18.867 +00:00",
            "Modify_Dt": "2016-10-09 19:33:10.810 +00:00",
            "Client_Name": "Aussie Bike Auto & Boat Loans South",
            "Client_Code": "GGT31",
            "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
          },
          {
            "App_ID": 2878070,
            "App_Ref": "alliso",
            "Status": "Quicklink",
            "Error_Code": null,
            "Error_Message": null,
            "Create_Dt": "2016-10-09 21:55:49.220 +00:00",
            "Modify_Dt": "2016-10-09 21:55:49.220 +00:00",
            "Client_Name": "KChristoforidis",
            "Client_Code": "GGT05",
            "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
          }...
    ],
        "Current_Dt": "2016-11-13 22:52:41.581 +00:00",
        "Last_App_Dt": "2016-10-11 01:42:25.470 +00:00",
        "Count": 65,
        "Total": 65
      }
}
```

I am able to output the "Success" bool from the Response but I am unable to get back anything else from the response as I am getting a **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** error when I try to do the following:

```
foreach (Application app in outPutResponse.jsonResponse.Applications)
{
    ApplicationBuffer.AddRow();
    ApplicationBuffer.AppID = app.App_ID;
    ApplicationBuffer.AppRef = app.App_Ref;
    ApplicationBuffer.Status = app.Status;

}
```

I also can't return the Response "jsonResponse" to the outputBuffer with an error "can not implicitly convert jsonResponse to BlobColumn"

I also can't return the Response value from outPutResponse.jsonResponse with the following errors:

```
    RawBuffer.AddRow();
    RawBuffer.ResponseSuccess = outPutResponse.Success;
    RawBuffer.Response.AddBlobData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outPutResponse.jsonResponse));
```

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[])' has some invalid arguments
   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Script.Response' to 'char[]'**

This is my final stumbling block and I can't seem to get this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Newtonsoft JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) since that is a smart idea.

You have changed the property name to `jsonResponse` when the actual property name is `Response`.

If you want to changes the names as you like you have to decorate the properties with

```
[JsonProperty("myproperty_name")]
```

like  so:

```
public class Application
{
    [JsonProperty("App_ID")]
    public int App_ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("App_Ref")]
    public string App_Ref { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Error_Code")]
    public int? Error_Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Error_Message")]
    public string Error_Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Create_Dt")]
    public string Create_Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Modify_Dt")]
    public string Modify_Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Client_Name")]
    public string Client_Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Client_Code")]
    public string Client_Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Centrelink_Status")]
    public string Centrelink_Status { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("Applications")]
    public IList<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Current_Dt")]
    public string Current_Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Last_App_Dt")]
    public string Last_App_Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Response")]
    public Response jsonResponse { get; set; }
}
```

While I recommend the above example you could also use `Response` instead ofc:

```
public Response Response { get; set; }
```